# Quote (item) is missing but the order exists

Tags: sales-order, quote, quoteitem

I experience a strange issue: The order was placed successfully but I can't find any according quote.

```
mysql> select increment_id, entity_id, quote_id, created_at  from sales_flat_order where increment_id=100000432;
+--------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| increment_id | entity_id | quote_id | created_at          |
+--------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| 100000432    |      1029 |    10383 | 2015-10-28 23:12:13 |
+--------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from sales_flat_quote where entity_id=10383;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from sales_flat_quote_item where quote_id=10383;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Isn't there always a quote?

Any chance to create a quote on base of the order?

The issue I'm facing right now is that I can't pull any order information in backend because an extension is throwing an exception because of the missing quoteItemId.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take  a look at Admin -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart -> 
Quote Lifetime (days)

By default magento will delete quote that has been converted to order after 30 days (the created_at date is over a month ago),

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545128/are-unconverted-quote-records-ever-removed-in-magento

Comment: Thanks for your help! But does Magento also delete quotes which got converted into orders? I'm wondering because I find quotes in sales_flat_quote table back to 2010. Further its strange that the extension (Aitoc) relies on a quoteItemId in backend if these data are not persistent.

Comment: ONLY quote that got converted are deleted.

Comment: Magento also have similar issues where you can not access a custom file upload option after the quote is deleted

Comment: Please provide more information on the error that you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from an enterprise point of view, there is a quote cleaner cron job that runs and cleans (deletes) quotes every X days. I think the default is 30 (which could explain why the original quote above is gone).

On the backend, go to *System* -> *Configuration* -> *Sales* -> *Checkout* and checkout the section  **Shopping Cart**.

It calls the method **cleanExpiredQuotes** in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Observer.php